# timeout when trying to log into my Instagram account with curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to log into my Instagram account with curl
But unfortunately, I run into problems and this does not happen!

The code I am trying is this

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/accounts/login/ajax");
$fields = array(
    'username' => '',
    'password' => ''
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

No matter how hard I try, I hit a dead end and there is really no way for me not to try!
What do you guys suggest? Should I use other options in curl?
If yes, please tell me

Meanwhile, this is my error:

> bool(false) Error:Failed to connect to [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com) port 443
> after 21026 ms: Timed out

I tried this

And I expected to be able to log into my Instagram account, but it wasn't!

Comment: I'm reading some suggestions that this may be an old unsupported API. Where did you get the login information / api doc from?

Comment: got it myself using Inspect

Comment: The error message appears to be because the PHP code can't even connect to the instagram server. Are you sure the firewall (of the machine where the PHP code is running) allows outbound connections on port 443?

Comment: I am not sure!
Can you tell me how to understand this?

Comment: By looking at the firewall settings on the machine in question. Exactly how you do that will depend on your O/S and/or firewall product

Comment: But it's like that only for some sites!
For example, it does not give this error for other sites

Comment: Do those other sites also require you to connect via HTTPS on port 443?

Comment: Another thing you can do, if you're testing from your local machine, is use a tool like Wireshark to trace the request and see exactly where in the network it gets blocked

Comment: No, those other sites are very simple
But this is really stuck, what should I do to solve it now?

Comment: That code works for me answering with "Bad Request". I bet, Insta put in some protecting mechanisms like UserAgents.

Comment: My friend, what is your opinion to solve this problem?

Comment: `No, those other sites are very simple`...so...that statement is quite vague and imprecise, but if what you're saying is that they are connecting on a different port (e.g. HTTP over port 80), then the issue could still be that the firewall blocks 443 outbound

Comment: Anyway, my guidance (regardless of network/firewall-related issues) when trying to connect to a site like would always be to use the official API, and [follow its official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api), which you don't seem to be doing. Instagram v1 API is no longer supported, as far as I can see.

Comment: _"What do you guys suggest?"_ - that you stop _trying to do_, what you are not _supposed to do_ in the first place. Instagram does not _want_ people to use any such automation on their frontend pages. And they have plenty of counter measures applied against it.

Comment: You could login with a browser as you normally do and then store the cookies in a file and use them with curl. See my answer as a suggestion: https://superuser.com/questions/186609/how-do-i-transfer-copy-cookies-from-one-browser-to-another-or-same-browser-fro/1757000#1757000